# Complex number as a divisor in synthetic division

Tags: complex-numbers

For the following exercises, use synthetic division to determine the quotient involving a complex number.

Problem
 + 1 /  +

Answer
1 + 1 −  /  +

I get the correct answer when I do it via long division but I don't get the same answer for synthetic.

Comment: What's the difference between long division and synthetic?  And how can we know why you got the wrong answer by synthetic division if  we don't know what you did?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long division:
$$\require{enclose}
\begin{array}{rll}
    1 \phantom{000}\\[-3pt]
   x+i \enclose{longdiv}{\quad x+1\phantom{000}}\kern-.2ex \\[-3pt]
      \underline{x+i\phantom{000}} \\[-3pt]
         1-i \\[-3pt]
  \end{array}$$
Synthetic division:
$$\require{enclose}
\begin{array}{rll}
   -i\;\; \enclose{longdiv}{\quad1\qquad1\phantom{000}}\kern-.2ex \\[-3pt]
      \underline{\phantom{0000}-i\phantom{000}} \\[-3pt]
         1\qquad 1-i \\[-3pt]
  \end{array}$$
In both cases you end up with: quotient $\;1\;$ and remainder $\;1-i\;$
[Here](https://www.purplemath.com/modules/synthdiv.htm) is a good summary polynomial synthetic division.

Comment: I had completely forgotten to only leave the -i as oppose to x+i in the synthetic division. I spent about 2 1/2 hours redoing this problem. I feel like a dumb-ass. But appreciative of your help and this website. Thank you!

Comment: Np! We all make dumb mistakes sometimes!

Answer (score 1):

This is what my synthetic division looks like.  What does your look like?

$\begin{array}{c|cc} &1&1\\-i&&-i\\\hline&1&1-i\end{array}$

Otherwise, I would say

$\frac {x+1}{x+i} = \frac {(x-i) -i + 1}{x+i} = 1 + \frac {1-i}{x+i}$

Comment: Thank you for your help.